# Callback fuction is not getting called

Tags: ros, callback, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I am new to ROS. I want to send messages in the form of string from Node1->Node2 and Node2->Node1. As Node1 can publish and Node2 can subscribe to the messages. Node2 can publish the message but in Node1 callback function is not getting called.

Program for Node1(talker)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
from number_generation import give_prime, secret_no
from modulo_operations import calculate

def callback2(data):
    rospy.loginfo('I heard %s', data.data)

def talker():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('chatter1', String, queue_size=1)
    pub1 = rospy.Publisher('chatter', String, queue_size=1)
    rospy.init_node('talker', anonymous=True)
    P=str(give_prime())
    q=str(give_prime())
    secret = secret_no()
    Server = str(calculate(int(P), int(q), int(secret)))
    rospy.loginfo(P)
    rospy.loginfo(q)
    pub.publish(P)
    pub1.publish(q)
    rospy.Subscriber('c', String, callback2)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        talker()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

Program for Node2(listener)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
from number_generation import secret_no
from modulo_operations import calculate

P='asdasd'
q='ygyg'
secret = 2
client = 13

def callback(data):
       global P
       P=int(data.data)
       rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + 'I heard %s', P)


def callback1(data):
        global q
        global secret
        global client 
        q=int(data.data)
        rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + 'I heard %s', q)
        sum()   

def sum():  
        global secret
        secret = secret_no()
        client = str(calculate(int(P), int(q), int(secret)))
        print 'calculation', client
        pub2.publish(client)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
        pub2 = rospy.Publisher('c',String,queue_size=1)
        rospy.Subscriber('chatter', String, callback)
        rospy.Subscriber('chatter1', String, callback1)

        rospy.spin()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304569/callback-fuction-is-not-getting-called/) by [Anuja_Rane](https://answers.ros.org/users/37849/anuja_rane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-10-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect this may be a problem of the timing of publishing and setting up the listeners.

A listener object takes a short period of time to attach to a topic before it will start receiving messages. in Node1 you are publishing on the topic `chatter1` then then subscribing to the topic for the expected reply `c`. It is possible that the subscriber is not set up in time for it to catch the reply sent by Node2.

I recommend moving the line `rospy.Subscriber('c', String, callback2)` before the publish commands and adding a 1 second delay after it to make sure it's setup before you publish the test messages.

Let us know if this fixes your problem.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anuja_Rane](https://answers.ros.org/users/37849/anuja_rane/) on 2018-10-02**:
It fixed my problem :)
Thank you so much

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-10-02**:
Great, thanks for letting us know.